# Typefaces on different devices

Tags: android, fonts, android-typeface

I made a helper class that loads typefaces from a font folder in Assets directory.

I noticed that some fonts load on some devices as intend, and on others, the font looks like an Arial font, the calligraphy of the font lost.

I ran the program on 2 physical devices, both Note 4, one running Android v 5.0.1 and the other 5.1.1

What could be the possible cause?

EDIT: the font in question is freely availabe for personal use
http://www.1001freefonts.com/windsong.font

the code (simplified and caching removed):

```
public static void setTitleTypeface(TextView tv) {
Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(tv.getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/windsong.ttf");
  tv.setTypeface(t);
}
```

Comment: What fonts were you trying to load? Some devices may not have the capability to render them.

Comment: free public domain fonts, one such font is called cac_champagne

Comment: MIght be best to edit your question to include the examples of fonts you are trying to load. Rather than long dwindled comments. Please include as much info as you can [MCVE] screenshots of font, and clarify what devices, also, more importantly, what versions of Android on those devices also (Are they stock, manufacturer's own, or Cyanogenmod)

Comment: Bit more details is needed! When android cannot render a font type, it will fall back to a system defined or roboto font, which is what you have described in your question. Do you have the logcat where the issue appears? How are you caching the font? See comment #7 on [this google issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904)

Comment: My code is almost exactly like the link you sent, but I didn't include caching in the script for the sake of brevity and because even without caching it it didn't work.
You actually answered my question when you said that this is normal behavior when android cannot render the font. Thanks. I will now lookup solutions to failed rendering and answer my question